# How do I make a div full screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flot

I am using [Flot](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/) to graph some of my data and I was thinking it would be great to make this graph appear fullscreen (occupy full space on the monitor) upon clicking on a button. Currently, my `div` is as follows:

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width:800px;height:600px"></div>
```

Of course, the style attribute is only for testing. I will move this to `CSS` after during the actual design. Is there anyway I could make this div fullscreen and still preserve all event handling?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

When you say "full-screen", do you mean like full-screen for the computer, or for taking up the entire space in the browser?

You can't force the user into full-screen `F11`; however, you can make your div full screen by using the following CSS

```
div {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

This will of course assume your div is child of the `<body>` tag. Otherwise, you'd need to add the following in addition to the above code.

```
div {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
```

Comment: I personally prefer `div {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;}`

Comment: @Codemonkey, that's a nice solution, *assuming* you don't need to support IE 6.

Comment: This won't work if the div is contained within another div which has 'relative' positioning set. In this case, you either need to remove relative positioning from parent divs, or use jQuery to .prepend the div to the body element.

Comment: That's true for any type of absolute positioning; however, it can be safely assumed that when a veil is being applied, it exists within the top most parent; aka, the body tag.

Comment: you indeed CAN make the browser go real full-screen (at least if you have a user action to grant you the right) with the HTML5 fullscreen API! Please look at Tracker1's answer a little further down here! :-/

Comment: Basically, it is not fullscreen. It calls full width or height.

Comment: Try 100vh and vw

Comment: And how does youtube do it? You can fullscreen a video and then literally sroll down and see the rest of the page too while staying in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 140):

You can use HTML5 Fullscreen API for this (which is the most suitable way i think).

The fullscreen has to be triggered via a user event (click, keypress) otherwise it won't work.

Here is a button which makes the div fullscreen on click. And in fullscreen mode, the button click will exit fullscreen mode.

```js
$('#toggle_fullscreen').on('click', function(){
  // if already full screen; exit
  // else go fullscreen
  if (document.fullscreenElement) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else {
    $('#container').get(0).requestFullscreen();
  }
});
```

```css
#container{
  border:1px solid red;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <p>
    <a href="#" id="toggle_fullscreen">Toggle Fullscreen</a>
  </p>
  I will be fullscreen, yay!
</div>
```

Please also note that Fullscreen API for Chrome does not work in non-secure pages. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.

Another thing to note is the :fullscreen CSS selector. You can append this to any css selector so the that the rules will be applied when that element is fullscreen:

```
#container:fullscreen {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    }
```

Comment: This is the real answer (I was looking for)

Comment: Me too - this is definitely the correct way to do it! Sometimes I'm baffled by what people accepts as a right answer. :-(

fiddling with the width and height might make your div fill out the entire window, but that's no way the same as going full screen! :-(

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem to work when running the snippet here - but moving the code to a JSFiddle works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/352cg8bv/

Comment: This is definitely the better answer. It's finally tied with the accepted answer for upvotes!

Comment: dude, you are going places... alleluyah !

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was the best!

Comment: Awesome!  add (CSS style) `background-color: #fff;` to make the full screen background appear white (appears black otherwise, in Firefox v88).

Comment: Your a genius in my eyes! We struggled with fullscreen in classroom for full day until finding this:) Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. If you need Scrollbars use `overflow: auto !important;` in the `:fullscreen` selector

Comment: Now it is 2022, you can probably remove the support for the experimental, vendor-prefixed versions of the API from this answer. They bloat the code a *lot* for no real benefit this decade.

Answer (score 31):

CSS way:

```css
#foo {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

JS way:

```
$(function() {
    function abso() {
        $('#foo').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            width: $(window).width(),
            height: $(window).height()
        });
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
        abso();         
    });

    abso();
});
```

Comment: this solution works perfectly. I had to create a **wrapper** `div` that I applied this styling to, and it's child elements continue to work as previously desired!
Cheers!

Comment: I just wrote this: `{position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;}` and now it works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 24):

For fullscreen of browser rendering area there is a simple solution supported by all modern browsers.

```
div#placeholder {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

The only notable exception is the Android below 4.3 - but ofc only in the system browser/webview element (Chrome works ok).

Browser support chart: http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

For fullscreen of monitor please use HTML5 Fullscreen API

Comment: this is working like a charm in an android WebView, thank you sir!
#graph { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }

Answer (score 15):

```
.widget-HomePageSlider .slider-loader-hide {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: Observe that most answers contain some explanation and discussion, not just code.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me because my modal dialog's html was within another div that was position: relative. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Can use FullScreen API like this

```
function toggleFullscreen() {
  let elem = document.querySelector('#demo-video');

  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
    elem.requestFullscreen().catch(err => {
      alert(`Error attempting to enable full-screen mode: ${err.message} (${err.name})`);
    });
  } else {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

Demo

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('#park-pic');

elem.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  toggleFullScreen();
}, false);

function toggleFullScreen() {

  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
    elem.requestFullscreen().catch(err => {
      alert(`Error attempting to enable full-screen mode: ${err.message} (${err.name})`);
    });
  } else {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

```css
#container{
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  padding:10px;
}
#park-pic {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>
    <a href="#" id="toggle-fullscreen">Toggle Fullscreen</a>
  </p>
  <img id="park-pic"
      src="https://storage.coverr.co/posters/Skate-park"></video>
</div>
```

P.S: Using [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js) nowadays. A simple wrapper for cross-browser usage of the JavaScript Fullscreen API.

Comment: +1 as you are the _only_ person to answer the specific "occupy full space on the monitor" the OP asked for

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest one.

```css
#divid {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

u can try this..

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width:auto;height:auto"></div>
```

width and height depends on your flot or graph..

hope u want this...

or

By clicking, u can use this by jquery

```
$("#placeholder").css("width", $(window).width());
$("#placeholder").css("height", $(window).height());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use document height if you want to show it beyond the visible area of browser(scrollable area).

CSS Portion

```
#foo {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

JQuery Portion

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#foo').css({
       width: $(document).width(),
       height: $(document).height()
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="placeholder" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;"></div>
```

Comment: This is already in the answer by Daryl and your answer doesn't bring anything new

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 5.0 this is incredibly easy now. Just toggle these classes on and off the full screen element.

```
w-100 h-100 position-absolute top-0 start-0 bg-white
```