# Highchart in new window

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, highcharts

I use highcharts to display a chart in my page.
It works fine, but some times data in graph is too "condensed" so I should find a way to see the graph in a greater size.

I read several posts over internet on this subject:
- in general they suggest to use highslide, but i don't want to, as my page is already overlaoded by scripts
-somebody tries to pop up the content in a popup, it could fit to me but I didn't succeed
- the only quasi-working example which fits to me seems to be the following:
(inside the options object I add this properties).

```
exporting: {
                    buttons: {
                        popUpBtn: {
                            symbol: 'square',
                            _titleKey: 'FullScreenButtonTitle',
                            x: -60,
                            symbolSize:18,
                            symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
                            hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
                            onclick: function () {
                                var win=window.open('','','location=0,titlebar=0,status=0,width=780,height=350');
                                win.focus();
                                var divtag = win.document.createElement("div");
                                divtag.id = "div1";
                                win.document.body.appendChild(divtag);
                                win.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="script/highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>\
                                                                    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/highcharts/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>');
                                this.options.renderTo=divtag;
                                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(this.options);

                                win.document.close();
                            }
                        },
                        exportButton: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        printButton: {
                            enabled: true
                        }

                    }
                }
```

However it is not working, as the div tag is not inserted and all i get is this

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script/highcharts/js/highcharts.js">  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/highcharts/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head></html>
```

I can't understand the error.
I know it should be something simple but I can't get out alone.

**--EDIT ---**

I finally understood which could be a working strategy: create a "chartpopup.html" page, and passing it the parameters needed to build the copy of the graph I visualize.

So now I have:

index.html:

```
    chartOptions = {
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'example',
                    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0]
                }]    
          //// CUT SOME CODE

                exporting: {
                    buttons: {
                        popUpBtn: {
                            enabled:true,
                            symbol: 'square',
                            _titleKey: 'FullScreenButtonTitle',
                            x: -60,
                            symbolSize:18,
                            symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
                            hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
                            onclick: function () {
                                look this!--------> generalPurposeGlobalVar = this;
                                var win=window.open('./chartpopup.html','Full Size Chart','location=0,titlebar=0,status=0,width=780,height=650');

                            }
                        },
                        exportButton: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        printButton: {
                            enabled: true
                        }

                    }
                }
            };
        this.highChart=new Highcharts.Chart(this.chartOptions);
```

and chartpopup.html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Chart full Size</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.7.1-min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script/highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script/highcharts/js/modules/exporting.js">              </script>

   </head>
   <body>

   <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 650; margin: 0 auto"></div>

   <script>
   var chart;

   $(document).ready(function() {

       var mychart=window.opener.generalPurposeGlobalVar;

       mychart.options.chart.renderTo= 'container';
       chart = new Highcharts.Chart(mychart.options);


   });
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

This two pages are actually working ONLY with the default graph. If I modify and re-render the graph, I'm not able to reproduce it on the popup page!

The code I use to modify the graph is basically this:

```
        this.chartOptions.series=[{name:field.split('_').join('\n')}];
        this.highChart.destroy();
        this.highChart=new Highcharts.Chart(this.chartOptions);
        this.highChart.xAxis[0].setCategories(_.isEmpty(mygroups) ? [] : mygroups);
        this.highChart.series[0].setData([]);
        this.highChart.setTitle({text: this.highChart.title.text},{text:(field.split('_').join(' ')),  });
        this.highChart.redraw();//
   [...]
        self.highChart.series[0].addPoint(result);//it's a point I calculated before
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: uh, yes, of course, I forgot to mention it:
 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null`

Comment: Also, any other suitable way of having a wider graph (possibly not using additional js libraries) is acceptable for me, if you have any suggestion...

Comment: Yeah it looks like you're accessing the DOM in the popup before it's available. The solution aschuler presents will work because you're pointing to an existing page.

Comment: so you sugegst i do this: 1) open an existing page in the popup, 2) working on the html elements contained in this page. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes it should resolve your issue. Note that he's using the jQuery event listener to fire the code off on document.ready. This link here explains what jQuery's really listening for in that event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery This is a good way to ensure that the DOM is ready to be accessed via javascript.

Comment: Still getting errors? Can you update your code and explain what's happening please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wandering around and asking questions, I found out that the best way to do it is to make fullscreen the div that contains the chart.

It's a very simple solution but it works.

This post is very helpful [How do I make a div full screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130397/how-do-i-make-a-div-full-screen)

A function like the following should  do the trick on  a "#graph" div:

```
function fullscr() {

        $('#graph').css({
            width: $(window).width(),
            height: $(window).height()
        });

    }
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an Highcharts exemple working with an "oldschool" popup :

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>highcharts foobar</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:open_chart_popup();">Open Chart Popup</a>
<script>
    function open_chart_popup() {
        window.open('popup.html', 'chart popup title', 'width=1680px height=1050px');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>highcharts foobar</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>
var chart;

$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If this solution doesn't fit to you, could you tell us which JavaScript libraries you use (this example relies on jQuery). As the documentation says, highcharts requires either jQuery, Mootools or Prototype : http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use

If you are able to use jQuery, you can replace that popup by using some cooler effects like those ones : http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Despite of that, if you want assistance for your script, could you consider making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), i'm not able to reproduce your error.

**EDIT :**

Okay, so you have all the stuff to deal with that.

I see two options :

- You send the user input `series` JSON data to your server by an AJAX request. Then your server send you back a view or a bunch of html/js containing your highchart with the user datas. Back to the client, you do wathever you want with that (like triggering a popup containing the graph). I'm not too comfortable with backbone but i'm sure you can generate a template and render it back (this may help http://japhr.blogspot.fr/2011/08/getting-started-with-backbonejs-view.html)
- The other solution would be to directly set your template (containing the graph) to the view but hidding him by default. Then, when the `series` are correctly setted by the user, you simply display the template (in a popup for example). This solution avoid a server call, so I would suggest that.

**EDIT 2 :**

So, I've made a jsFiddle showing a basic example on how to update a chart based on a user input : http://jsfiddle.net/MxtkM/

The example updates the last value of all the series on the graph, here is how :

```
$('#december_value').bind('keyup', function() {
    var user_input_value = parseFloat($(this).val()); // cast to float

    for (var s in chart.series) { // loop through the series
        var old_data = chart.series[s].data;
        var new_data = [];

        for (var d in old_data ) { // loop through data objects
           new_data.push(old_data[d].config); // config property contains the y value
        }

        new_data[new_data.length - 1] = user_input_value; // update the last value

        chart.series[s].setData(new_data); // use setData method to refresh the datas of the serie
    }
});
```

This example use the method setData by providing a new data array.
If this doesn't fit your needs, there is an another method to refresh your graph in whitch you rerender all the graph by doing `var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);`. (This is explained in the links above).

This two links are also a good read :

- [Reload chart data via JSON with Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210879/reload-chart-data-via-json-with-highcharts)
- http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use (part 3 and 4)

Now you shoud be able to do whatever you want with your graph based on a user input.

Comment: Hi aschuler thanks for your answer. My problem is that the data used to fill the chart (the `series`) is dynamically generated from user input from the main page (and not fetched from the server). That's why I can't use a brand new page. I use colorbox for popups, jquery, jquery-ui (a lot of stuff!) all in a backbone.js framework (so I use _.underscore.js as well) and the page is already quite heavy.

Comment: I suppose the best solution is to dynamically generate a page which displays in a new window or in a popup. But I have problems in doing it. Do yo have any idea on how to create dynamically the page content (with script included) and then rendere it in a new page/popup/window? Also: do you think it is a good strategy?

Comment: Hi aschuler, the second options is exactly what I was going to do. I understood, thanks also to Alex Morales comment, that the best is open an existing page and working on its elements... This is exactly the point where I'm little bit stucked.

Comment: thanks for the edit, still I can't get any result. Please have a look at my edit.

Comment: @Adreien Schuler: i would be happy to award you with the bounty, but... could you please privde little additional help? tnx.

Comment: Do you have any errors ? You must `parseFloat()` the user input values before adding them to the `series` array. Otherwise, try to comment superfluous options and focus on the `series` array, log it and see how he looks like. He's maybe not well formated.

Comment: You should've given the bounty anyway since your original question was answered. This is really a different issue you're having.

Comment: HI Alex, I didn't feel my oroiginal quesition was answerd, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The Best solution will be HTML5 Fullscreen API for fullscreen

```
function fullScreen(){
     var elem = document.getElementById("highchart_div_id");
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
}
```

However, this piece of code only works in New Generation Browsers and I have hands on working output from `Google chrome` and `Mozilla Firefox`

Good Day