# Trying to center login form in between header and footer

Tags: html, css

How do I center the login form in between the header and footer? It is right now touching the header but I need it to be centered in between the header and the footer. As you can see below, I tried setting the width and height of the child element (which is the container) of the parent element (which in this case is the  tag. Any help would be wonderful. I am new to coding, and am looking to learn the right way to do things. Thank you!! 
I tried following this link: [How do I make a div full screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130397/how-do-i-make-a-div-full-screen) but was not successful.

```css
  
        .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
        #col-6 {
            display: flex;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #login {
            font-size: .95em;
            padding-top: 6px;
    
        }
        #username::placeholder {
            font-size: .75em;
        }
    
        #password::placeholder {
            display: none;
            font-size: .75em;
        }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 412px) {
        #col-6 {
            display: flex;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #login {
            font-size: .95em;
            padding-top: 6px;
    
        }
        #username::placeholder {
            font-size: .75em;
        }
    
        #password::placeholder {
            font-size: .74em;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 mx-auto" id="col-6">
          <div class="card" id="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <p class="h3" id="login">LOGIN</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form class="form" role="form" autocomplete="off" id="loginForm" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                  <label for="username">Username</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder=""
                    required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-danger" id="button" (click)="onClickSubmitButton()">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Pls dont include such a big link in your post

Comment: will do, thank you for the advice!!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by making the card itself a flexbox with flex-direction set to row(by default), justify-content: space-between; and align-items: center; to space and align them equally. to learn more on using flexbox visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Flexbox

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```css
html,body{
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 100%;
font-family: 'Numans', sans-serif;
}

.container{
height: 100%;
align-content: center;
}

.card{
height: 370px;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
width: 400px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
}

.card-header h3{
color: white;
}

.input-group-prepend span{
width: 50px;
background-color: #FFC312;
color: black;
border:0 !important;
}

input:focus{
outline: 0 0 0 0  !important;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 !important;

}

.login_btn{
color: black;
background-color: #FFC312;
width: 100px;
}

.login_btn:hover{
color: black;
background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<!--Bootsrap 4 CDN-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
  <div class="card">
   <div class="card-header">
    <h3>LOGIN</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">
    <form>
     <div class="input-group form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
      
     </div>
     <div class="input-group form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-danger" id="button" (click)="onClickSubmitButton()">Submit</button>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using bootstrap here. You may not linked the bootstrap CDN correctly. Try the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
            #col-6 {
                display: flex;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #login {
                font-size: .95em;
                padding-top: 6px;

            }
            #username::placeholder {
                font-size: .75em;
            }

            #password::placeholder {
                display: none;
                font-size: .75em;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 412px) {
            #col-6 {
                display: flex;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #login {
                font-size: .95em;
                padding-top: 6px;

            }
            #username::placeholder {
                font-size: .75em;
            }

            #password::placeholder {
                font-size: .74em;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 mx-auto" id="col-6">
              <div class="card" id="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <p class="h3" id="login">LOGIN</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <form class="form" role="form" autocomplete="off" id="loginForm" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                      <label for="username">Username</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                      <label for="password">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder=""
                        required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 text-center">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-danger" id="button" (click)="onClickSubmitButton()">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two adjustments you need to make here. First, a height percentage on the root element (.container) can't reference the innerHeight of the window. Use vh (viewport height) units, instead. Set the height of `.container` to `100vh`. The div will expand to the height of the viewport.

Second, you can center the form by setting `display:flex` and  `align-items:center;` on `.container.` `align-items:center;` will center the form vertically. If you want to also center the form horizontally add `justify-content:center.`

CSS rules for .container should look like this:

```
   .container {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100vh;
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
   }
```

A great reference for css flexbox is here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/