# Make div go fullscreen inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, fullscreen

I have the html like below:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>Welcome.</div>
      <iframe src='otherpagecontent' width='594' height='334'>
        #docuemnt
        <html>
            <body>
              <div style='color:yellow'>
              This should not show in fullscreen.
              </div>
              <div style='color:yellow'>
              This should not show in fullscreen.
              </div>
              <div id='fullscreen' style='color:blue;'>
              This should go fullscreen only.
              </div>
              <div style='color:red'>
              This should not show in fullscreen.
              </div>
              <div style='color:red'>
              This should not show in fullscreen.
              </div>
            </body>
        </html>
      </iframe>
      <iframe src='differentpage'>
        #docuemnt
        <button onclick="launchFullscreen(document.getelementByID('fullscreen'));">Launch Fullscreen</button>
      </iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

In JS:

```
this.launchFullscreen= function (element) {
    var requestFullScreen = (element.requestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullscreen);
    requestFullScreen.apply(element);
}
```

Result in `Request for fullscreen was denied because of FeaturePolicy directives.`

How can I get this `<div id='fullscreen'>` to go fullscreen?
Should I change the CSS for this `<div>`, or bind the request from somewhere else?

PS: This work fine on Chrome, but issue occur on Firefox.

Comment: [This article](https://redstapler.co/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe/) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use CSS for this.
You can't force the user into full-screen by **F11**; however, you can make your div full screen by using the following CSS

```
div {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

This will of course assume your div is child of the  tag. Otherwise, you'd need to add the following in addition to the above code.

```
div {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
```

from:[How do I make a div full screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130397/how-do-i-make-a-div-full-screen)

Comment: Sorry, but firefox have strictly fullscreen CSS `:not(:fullscreen)` and I don't quite know how to apply this CSS. Beside that, can we make a postMessage to reach cross-orign from internal iframe?

Answer (score 1):

You might try this

```
<iframe src="myurl.in"
frameborder="0" 
marginheight="0" 
marginwidth="0" 
width="100%" 
height="100%" 
scrolling="auto"></iframe >
```

from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-fullscreen-iframe/